# Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS) in the Rackspace Cloud Files Python API

Tags: python, cors, rackspace-cloud

I'm trying to [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) on my Rackspace Cloud Files. According to [the docs](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Assigning_CORS_Headers_to_Requests-d1e2120.html), I can add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but I don't see how to do that with the [Python `python-cloudfiles` module API](http://packages.python.org/python-cloudfiles/):

```
  conn = cloudfiles.get_connection('apaidnerd', 's3cr3t')
  container = conn.get_container('warez')

  obj = container.create_object('foo.png')
  obj.load_from_filename('/path/to/foo.png')

  # ...what's next?
```

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the undocumented `headers` property of `Object`:

```
obj.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'                                               
obj.sync_metadata()
```

Comment: Is it necesary to call the sync_matadata() ??

Comment: I think so, but I can't remember.