# setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin using Rackspace Cloud Java API

Tags: rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I am using the Java API for uploading files to Rackspace Cloud. I am trying to figure out how to set the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on the files that I am uploading. I found another link that talks about setting this header using Python Binding here:

[Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS) in the Rackspace Cloud Files Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424443/setting-access-control-allow-origin-cors-in-the-rackspace-cloud-files-python-a)

Is there a similar API with Java Binding as well? I can't seem to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of a Java guy, but per [this](http://www.rackspace.com/blog/cors-headers-for-cloud-files-content-available-now/) it looks like metadata needs to be set on your containers, with a key of `X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, and a value of a space separated list of allowed origins.

Thus you need to use whatever function is used to set container metadata for the jclouds API.

It appears that this could be done on creation like so (based on adaptation of [this code](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/master/rackspace/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/rackspace/cloudfiles/CreateContainer.java)):

```
CreateContainerOptions options = CreateContainerOptions.Builder
            .withMetadata(ImmutableMap.of("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));

swift.getApi().createContainer(Constants.CONTAINER, options);
```

Looking through the docs, I found the following function in org.jclouds.openstack.swift.CommonSwiftClient:

`boolean setContainerMetadata(String container,
                           Map<String,String> containerMetadata)`

It therefore looks like you should be able to do what you're looking for with something like the following:

```
swift.getApi().setContainerMetadata(container, ImmutableMap.of("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
```

Comment: Great answer. I made one edit (pending peer review) to it to remove "X-Container-Meta-". jclouds handles adding that for you so including it would actually cause the example not to work. Other than that it's spot on.